# How do I build R from sources on macOS?

Tags: r, macos, build

I have seen many guides on Stack Overflow and elsewhere for building R *packages* from sources on macOS.

But what steps are required to build R *itself* from sources on macOS?  And how do these differ between Intel- and ARM-based Macs, i.e., how is the process different on Apple silicon (M1 or M2)?

For simplicity, I would like to restrict attention to the versions of macOS currently receiving security patches: Big Sur, Monterey, and Ventura.

#### What I've tried

I am running Big Sur on an M1 Mac. I obtained a daily snapshot of R's sources [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R/daily/) and have installed the mandatory tools listed [here](https://mac.r-project.org/tools/), namely Xcode and GNU Fortran.

So far I've tried

```bash
$ curl -LO https://stat.ethz.ch/R/daily/R-patched.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf R-patched.tar.gz
$ cd R-patched
$ ./configure
```

with the error

```
configure: error: No Fortran compiler found
```

so I guess that additional setup is required ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Since this answer is new-ish, I'd be grateful for comments/testing ...]*

The authoritative sources of information on this topic are the [R Installation and Admistration manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-admin.html) ("R-admin") and the [R for macOS Developers web page](https://mac.r-project.org/). This answer is an *unofficial* summary, parts of which are liable to become out of date *eventually* as macOS and CRAN's build system evolve.  As usual, `sudo` at your own risk.

### Background

As part of the GNU project, R uses the Autotools build system, which should be familiar to anyone who has developed software for Linux.  On most Linux systems, installing R's dependencies is easy enough and the build "just works".  Unfortunately, that is not the case at all on macOS, where installing the prerequisites and configuring the build correctly can require a careful reading of the documentation.  That has discouraged many macOS users from trying to diagnose and patch bugs in R itself.

This guide tries to present the necessary steps for a CRAN-like build as compactly as possible, without getting into details (for better or worse).  My hope is that a compact guide will help make the R-admin manual a bit less intimidating, especially for people who have never interacted with Autotools.

### What you will need

1. **A copy of R's sources.**  If you have Subversion installed
   on your system (try, e.g., `svn --version`), then you can
   check out the latest R-devel from R's Subversion repository
   with

   ```bash
   $ svn checkout https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/ R-devel
   ```

   or the latest R-patched with

   ```bash
   $ svn checkout https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-x-y-branch/ R-patched
   ```

   replacing `x-y` with `4-3` for R version 4.3, `4-2` for
   R version 4.2, and so on.  Otherwise, you can download and
   unpack one of the daily snapshots available
   [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R/daily/).
   For example:

   ```bash
   $ curl -LO https://stat.ethz.ch/R/daily/R-patched.tar.gz
   $ tar -xvf R-patched.tar.gz
   ```

   If you intend to build the recommended packages
   (e.g., **Matrix**) along with R, then you will need to download
   the corresponding sources.  R has a script for that:

   ```bash
   $ cd R-devel # or R-patched
   $ ./tools/rsync-recommended
   ```

   If you downloaded one of the daily snapshots, then the script
   may do nothing, since tarballs containing the package sources
   are typically already included in the snapshots.
2. **Command Line Tools for Xcode.**  These include Apple Clang and
   other tools needed to build libraries containing C and C++ code.
   You can install the latest version available for your version of
   macOS with:

   ```bash
   $ sudo xcode-select --install
   ```

   You can obtain older versions from your browser
   [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode).
   CRAN builds R 4.3.x for macOS 11.0 and newer using Xcode 14.2.
3. **GNU Fortran.**  To avoid binary incompatibilities,
   do *not* rely on Homebrew's `gfortran`.  Download and
   unpack the binary used by CRAN, which is available
   [here](https://github.com/R-macos/gcc-12-branch/releases):

   ```bash
   $ curl -LO https://github.com/R-macos/gcc-12-branch/releases/download/12.2-darwin-r0/gfortran-12.2-darwin20-r0-universal.tar.xz
   $ sudo tar -xvf gfortran-12.2-darwin20-r0-universal.tar.xz -C /
   $ sudo ln -sfn $(xcrun --show-sdk-path) /opt/gfortran/SDK
   ```
4. **MacTeX.** A LaTeX distribution is used to build PDF versions
   of the R manuals and of R package help pages and vignettes.
   You can download the MacTeX distribution from CTAN
   [here](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) if you can spare 5-10 GiB
   of disk space:

   ```bash
   $ curl -LO https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/MacTeX.pkg
   $ sudo installer -pkg MacTeX.pkg -target /
   ```

   If you prefer the much smaller BasicTeX, then you will have to
   install additional TeX packages, but that is beyond the scope
   of this question.
5. **XQuartz.**  Though not mandatory, XQuartz provides
   an implementation of the X Window System, which is
   needed for the `X11()` graphics device, for `View()`-ing
   and `edit()`-ing data frames, and for other graphical
   functionality.  Download and unpack a recent binary
   from the XQuartz web page
   [here](https://www.xquartz.org/releases/index.html):

   ```bash
   $ curl -LO https://github.com/XQuartz/XQuartz/releases/download/XQuartz-2.8.5/XQuartz-2.8.5.pkg
   $ sudo installer -pkg XQuartz-2.8.5.pkg -target /
   ```
6. **Additional external libraries, headers, and programs.**
   Some of these are mandatory
   (`libz`, `libbz2`, `liblzma`, `libpcre2-8`, `libcurl`).
   Others are optional but desirable enough that CRAN also
   installs them on its build system
   (`libjpeg`, `libpng`, `libtiff`, `libcairo`, `pkg-config`).
   GNU Texinfo is required (in addition to MacTeX) for building
   the PDF and Info versions of the R manuals whose sources are
   written in the Texinfo format.

   Simon Urbanek's [`recipes`](https://github.com/R-macos/recipes)
   build system provides a convenient mechanism for installing
   those components that are not already part of macOS.

   ```bash
   $ git clone https://github.com/R-macos/recipes.git
   $ cd recipes
   $ export PREFIX=/opt/R/$(uname -m)
   $ sudo -E bash ./build.sh r-base-dev
   ```

   That will install the components in the `r-base-dev` bundle
   under `/opt/R/x86_64` on Intel-based Macs and `/opt/R/arm64`
   on on ARM-based Macs.  Tools must be found on the search path
   in the next step, so at this point you will want to do:

   ```bash
   $ export PATH=/opt/R/$(uname -m)/bin:${PATH}
   ```

### Configuring the build

In the top level directory of R's sources, you'll find a script named `configure` and a file named `config.site`.  Create and change to a build directory and copy `config.site` there:

```bash
$ mkdir _build
$ cd _build
$ cp /path/to/config.site .
```

Edit your copy of `config.site` so that it contains the macro definitions below, setting:

- `ARCH` to the value of `uname -m`, namely `x86_64` on Intel-based Macs and `arm64` on ARM-based Macs.
- `OSVER` to `11.0` on Big Sur, `12.0` on Monterey, and `13.0` on Ventura (i.e., the floor of `sw_vers -productVersion`).  CRAN will use `11.0` as long as it continues to support Big Sur.

```makefile
CC=clang

CFLAGS="-Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=${OSVER} -arch ${ARCH} -falign-functions=64 -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"

CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/R/${ARCH}/include

FC=/opt/gfortran/bin/gfortran

FCFLAGS="-Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=${OSVER} -arch ${ARCH} -mtune=native"

LDFLAGS=-L/opt/R/${ARCH}/lib

CXX=clang++

CXXFLAGS="-Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=${OSVER} -arch ${ARCH} -falign-functions=64"

R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/R/${ARCH}/lib

PKG_CONFIG=/opt/R/${ARCH}/bin/pkg-config

PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/R/${ARCH}/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/R/${ARCH}/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/share/pkgconfig
```

Then run `configure` in your build directory with appropriate flags.  To emulate CRAN, your command line should look like this:

```bash
$ /path/to/configure --enable-R-framework --enable-memory-profiling --x-includes=/opt/X11/include --x-libraries=/opt/X11/lib
```

Note that you *must* add the flag `--without-recommended-packages` to the command line if you decided earlier to not run the `rsync-recommended` script.  In any case, if things are working, then you should see output ending with a summary similar to this one:

```
R is now configured for aarch64-apple-darwin22.4.0

  Source directory:            ../R-patched
  Installation directory:      /Library/Frameworks

  C compiler:                  clang  -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -arch arm64 -falign-functions=64 -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration
  Fortran fixed-form compiler: /opt/gfortran/bin/gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -mtune=native

  Default C++ compiler:        clang++ -std=gnu++14  -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -arch arm64 -falign-functions=64
  C++11 compiler:              clang++ -std=gnu++11  -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -arch arm64 -falign-functions=64
  C++14 compiler:              clang++ -std=gnu++14  -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -arch arm64 -falign-functions=64
  C++17 compiler:              clang++ -std=gnu++17  -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -arch arm64 -falign-functions=64
  C++20 compiler:              clang++ -std=gnu++20  -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -arch arm64 -falign-functions=64
  Fortran free-form compiler:  /opt/gfortran/bin/gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -mtune=native
  Obj-C compiler:          clang -g -O2 -fobjc-exceptions

  Interfaces supported:        X11, aqua
  External libraries:          pcre2, readline, curl
  Additional capabilities:     PNG, JPEG, TIFF, NLS, cairo, ICU
  Options enabled:             framework, shared BLAS, R profiling, memory profiling

  Capabilities skipped:        
  Options not enabled:         

  Recommended packages:        yes
```

You may decide to modify the flags passed to `configure` after running `/path/to/configure --help` and consulting the documentation there, as well as the more detailed documentation in R-admin.  Notably, `--enable-R-framework` can be replaced by `--enable-R-shlib` if you do not intend to run R inside of a GUI like R.app or RStudio.app.  In that case, R is installed under `/usr/local` unless you indicate otherwise by setting `--prefix=` on the command line.

If you have configured and would like to reconfigure with different flags, then do start by cleaning the build directory:

```bash
$ make distclean
```

If necessary, you can always remove the build directory and start anew.

### Building R

Just run:

```bash
$ make
```

At this point you should be able to run R directly from the build directory.

```bash
$ bin/R --version
```

### Checking the build

Before installing R—and certainly before submitting patches to R—verify that your build passes all of the relevant tests:

```bash
$ make check-devel
```

If a test fails, then you can diagnose the error by inspecting any `.fail` files in the `tests` subdirectory.

### (Un)installing the build

It is not at all necessary to install R.  For example, you might prefer to only install binaries built by CRAN.  But if you wanted to, then you would run:

```bash
$ sudo make install
```

And if you configured using `--enable-R-framework`, then you would add `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin` to your `PATH`, allowing you to run `R` in your shell without specifying its location.

You can always uninstall with:

```bash
$ sudo make uninstall
```

assuming that you have not destroyed the build directory.